Momentum for a First Person Controller in Godot 4
My First Person Controller (CharacterBody3D) currently has no momentum at all. By the way, I measure my movement speed in the debug panel (hotkey ~) with velocity.length() and when I get pushed by one of the platforms (see this video), my speed stays at 0 while I'm being pushed, which isn't how it supposed to be. What would be the best way to add a momentum/inertia feature and measure my current speed at all times?

Source:
https://github.com/CryptoMares/FPS-Player-Controller
Thanks!

You should be able to fix the platform with platform_on_leave. I do not know about the wall case (I haven't tested, I don't have much time to look into it now). However, the documentation mentions platform_wall_layers which might be a solution (idk). Addendum: It might also be that the code is not recognizing the platform as a platform. If you are moving it directly, use a AnimatableBody3D with sync_to_physics, if it is nested try other types of body (I recall running on some issue like that).

Sorry for the newbie question, but I've set the AnimatableBody3D like this, but I get no collision at all now. What am I doing wrong?

The picture is not loading for me. However, no collision at all implies you can't even have the character standing on it, which I would guess it is a matter of setting the collision layers. Also, you can enable visible collision shape in the debug menu to see if the colliders are positioned correctly while running the game from the editor.

Alternative link to that same image
No idea what to do with the collision layers yet, but thanks for the tip!

Ok, so you have a CSGBox3D with the body as a child. I'd assume the CSGBox3D does not have physics enabled, to let the AnimatableBody3D handle the collision. However, the CSGBox3D has a script, which makes me think in this case the AnimatableBody3D is not moving itself, but the CSGBox3D is moving. This is what I meant by having the AnimatableBody3D nested, I had issues with this before, in that configuration try StaticBody3D or CharacterBody3D for the platform. However, if you can, do it the other way around: put the CSGBox3D inside the AnimatableBody3D and move it.

Since you say you do not know about collision layers, I'm going to link you here: How do I detect collisions in Godot?. Assuming you haven't invested a lot of code on it, it should make thing easier.

Thank you! I'm gonna try all that.

Were you able to find a solution?

Not yet, unfortunately, but I will keep trying.

You can use AnimatableBody3D to implement static bodies that can be moved around, automatically updating their own linear and angular velocities for affecting colliding objects. Or, you can set manually such velocity values for StaticBody3Ds if you have static bodies that resemble moving surfaces (rolling tapes, etc.) This will ensure a consistent physics simulation and enable the momentum effects you described when combining an appropriate floor_snap_length value.

This is a First Person Controller, so it's in 3D. How would you translate this concept into 3D? Also, please try my controller out in Godot, if it's not too much trouble.

That's the same in 3D. I see you're using a CharacterBody for the player, this should be included in your question rather than leaving it to an external code repository.

Ok thanks. Even though I don't really understand — I will keep trying. What about the fact that my velocity isn't being calculated while I'm being pushed by one of the platforms? link

Static bodies are static for the engine. That's why they have constant_*_velocity properties so that you can emulate them moving around from a physics perspective: this makes them affect other colliding bodies' momenta. Your character body also snaps to the floor, so if you want it to be "launched" when pushed by a moving platform, you have to work around its snapping and friction properties. (Check my edited answer.)

Thank you! I will look into this and report back.

I completely forgot about the fact that Godot 4 allows to automatically compute momentum for platforms via the AnimatableBody classes! I updated my answer accordingly :)

I tried using the AnimatableBody3D, but it screws up the collision - it just doesn't work no matter what I try. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. This is hard :)
